Power BI Setting up primary key but need to clean rows with a null 1st, having problems
I am trying to set up the primary key on my table but the "Key column" dropdown selection keeps giving me an error stating (correctly) that there is a space in the column and I can't build a primary key column because of the space.
I've been looking at many Youtube videos that show how to remove rows with columns with nulls or spaces BUT they all show how to remove rows with multiple columns with spaces. I only want to look at the one column named, 'Hub/Site CLLI' and ignore all other columns.
So, I believe the fix is to first remove the row that has a space (or null) value in the specific column named 'Hub/Site CLLI'. Then assign the primary key to that column ignoring if there are spaces or nulls in the other columns.
Also, I need to make sure this is done each time the table is refreshed since there can be other spaces or nulls in the column in future refreshes.
Here's the steps that I've done so far ...

I import the csv file

Go to Model View

Select the imported file that is presented as a table

Here's where I want to assign a Primary Key

So I select the table's Properties -> Key Column,

I select the 'Hub Site/CLLI' column from my table on the dropdown box.

But I get the following error:

Column 'Hub/Site CLLI' in Table 'Power BI Hub CLLI' contains blank values and this is not allowed for columns on the one side of the many to one relationship or for columns that are used for primary key of a table. (Hub Site CLLI(156)).


I go to the Data View screen and confirm that there is a row with a blank (space) value in the 'Hub/Site CLLI' column.


